# SUP for iOS SQLite Encryption alogrithm

Tags: ios, sqlite, sup

Can anyone tell me what is the encryption algorithm used by SUP on iOS to encrypt the underlying database ?

Does it rely on SQLite EE (Encryption extension), and if so which of the 4 algorithm available is used ?

My guess is some sort of AES, but nowhere mentioned in the official documentation.

Or does SUP use a custom encryption not relying on SQLite EE ?

Answer (score 1):

Got an external reply from an SUP evangelist.
SUP relies on SQLite Encryption and uses AES-128 in OFB mode as cipher mode.